# Is there a way to use sp_OACreate with Authorization header, with Bearer and jwt token?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to use `sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1'` to post data using SQL Server 2008r2 and Authorization header, with Bearer and jwt token? The code below does not work, but hopefully outlines what I'm trying to do. Gets 401, but token works in Fiddler:

```
set @body = '{
  "id": "73135",
  "Objectives": [{
        "objt": "blah",
        "comment": "blah",
        "type": "blah",
        "index": "blah",
        "state": "blah"
  }]
}'


exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @obj OUT
if @hr <> 0 
      begin 
            set @msg = 'sp_OACreate failed' 
      end

exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'POST', 'https://myurl/731', false
if @hr <> 0 
       begin 
            set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' 
       end

EXEC sp_OAMethod @hr, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', 'Bearer long.jwt.here' 

exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type','application/json'
if @hr <> 0 
      begin 
            set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
      end

exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, @body
if @hr <> 0 
      begin 
             set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' 
      end
```

Comment: `exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, @body`?? Maybe `'send'` needed. What header requires `https://myurl/731`? Also `WinHttpRequest` adds `Charset=UTF-8` to `Content-Type` by default (as I remember). Try use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` instead of `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`

Comment: @gofr1 it gets a 401 so send is correct, and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1. The post is not getting past Oauth. My hunch is that the 'Authorization: Bearer jwt' syntax is incorrect. It works when using Fiddler header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
EXEC sp_OAMethod @hr, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', 'Bearer long.jwt.here'
```

To this:

```
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', 'Bearer long.jwt.here' 
if @hr <> 0 
      begin 
            set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
      end
```

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353229/is-there-a-way-to-use-sp-oacreate-with-authorization-header-with-bearer-and-jwt) I created a simply modified function for my needs.

```
create function GetPostAPI
(
    @method varchar(5),
    @url varchar(8000),
    @token NVARCHAR(2000),
    @params NVARCHAR(2000)
)
returns varchar(8000)
as 

BEGIN
DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(2000);

DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @internalToken INT;

SET @authHeader= 'Bearer ' + @token;
SET @contentType = 'application/json';

-- Open the connection.
--EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @internalToken OUT;
--IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'open', NULL, @method, @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader; 
if @ret <> 0 
      begin 
            set @ret = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' 
      end
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @internalToken, 'send', NULL, @params;

-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @internalToken, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @internalToken, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @internalToken, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Show the response.
--PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
--PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;

-- Close the connection.
EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @internalToken;
--IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);
return @responseText 
END
```

You can call it as below

```
DECLARE @method varchar(5)
DECLARE @url varchar(8000)
DECLARE @token NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @method='POST';
SET @url = 'https://.../api/v1.1/Users/authenticate';
SET @token=''
SET @params = '{
    "isim":"isim",
    "username": "admin1",
    "password": "admin"
}';  

select dbo.GetPostAPI(@method,@url,@token,@params) as sonuc
```

As you can see it works

[SQL Studio screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slC7r.png)